# Смена раскладки клавиатуры в системе

Tags: c#, winapi, клавиатура

Необходимо периодически менять раскладку системы, при этом сама программа в момент переключения не должна быть активной, соответственно ни `CurrentInputLanguage`, ни `LoadKeyboardLayout` не подходят (либо я не правильно их использую).

Что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нет функции "наделать дел в чужом процессе" (а обычно таких функций нет), то вам нужно загрузить свою динамическую библиотеку в чужой процесс и вызвать код "изнутри" него. Таким образом поступают всякого рода Пунто Свитчеры, файрволы и прочие утилиты.

C# использовать для таких вещей крайне не рекомендуется, потому что вместе с C# вы затащите в каждый процесс среду выполнения .NET. Это тяжеловесня штука, и не каждый процесс такому будет рад. Например, MS до сих пор не рекомендует писать расширения оболочки на управляемых языках (они реализованы как in-process COM-серверы, и грузятся во многие процессы в системе).

Ту часть приложения, которой нужно интимное взаимодействие со многими процессами, лучше написать, например, на C++.

**[Добавлено]**

Как выяснилось, вы можете воспользоваться `PostMessage` и `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`. [Пример на AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/24666-keyboard-layout-switcher/).

Comment: Покопался в интернетах, готового ничего не нашел, сам сделать подобное (пока) не могу.. с другими языками на Вы (как и с шарпом по большому счету).
Но, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @jackrv Вероятно, тогда вам рано приниматься за подобные вещи. Внедрение в чужой процесс — это очень опасная операция, к которой нужно относиться со всей серьёзностью, потому что она может обрушить и процесс, и систему, я уж не говорю про всевозможные уязвимости. / Что конкретно вы хотите сделать? Может, существуют более простые пути, например, можно попытаться найти подходящую готовую утилиту.

Comment: @ Athari, эдакая спам-программка. По таймеру отправляет в игру заданный текст с помощью `SendKeys.SendWait`. Проблема в том что текст может быть как на русском так и на английском языке, соответственно при несовпадении раскладка-текст получаются "крякозяблы" или вопросительные знаки.

Получается нужна переключалка раскладки Eng/Rus но с правами переключения чужих потоков.

Comment: @jackrv Обновил ответ.

Comment: @ Athari, вы имеете ввиду конструкцию вида `PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), 0x0419, 2, 0)`? У меня данный код вообще ничего не делает :(

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался, вот результат:

Для начала цепляем две ф-ции WinAPI из user32.dll

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
```

Говорил о двух а написал три, первая - для поиска хендла активного в текущий момент окна

Далее все предельно просто, загружаем код раскладки и отправляем его с помощью WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST (код 0x50) в активное окно:

```
string lang = "00000409";
int ret = LoadKeyboardLayout(lang, 1);
PostMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), 0x50, 1, ret);
```

Минимальный список языков:

```
"00000407" Немецкий (стандартный)
"00000409" Английский (США)
"0000040C" Французский (стандартный)
"0000040D" Финский
"00000410" Итальянский
"00000415" Польский
"00000419" Русский
"00000422" Украинский
"00000423" Белорусский
"00000425" Эстонский
"00000426" Латвийский
"00000427" Литовский
```

Я не совсем понял как, но код работает, а это главное!
Спасибо @Athari за помощь и правильный пинок в правильном направлении!

Answer (score 1):

в заголовке класса формы объявите переменную defLang следующим образом:

```
InputLanguage defLang;
```

в обработчике события Load вашей формы вставьте такой код:

```
InputLanguageCollection ilc = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages;
defLang = InputLanguage.DefaultInputLanguage;
foreach (InputLanguage il in ilc)
if (il.Culture.EnglishName.Contains("Rus"))
   InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = il;
```

в обработчике события FormClosed вашей формы вставьте такой код:

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = defLang;
```